# Bitmap image sharing on Facebook wall

Tags: android, android-sharing, facebook-share

I want to share screenshot of my application screen with some details like title,description on facebook wall. Please any one can help me how can i do this? I want to use facebookSDK. If any other options available for sharing please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that without using Facebook SDK with the help of facebook app installed in your phone. Just follow these simple steps

So first of all, you have to take screenshot of your app in the form of bitmap like this

```
View v1 = yourScreenShotView.getRootView();  
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap= v1.getDrawingCache();
```

After you get bitmap from above then you have to make uri of the bitmap like this

```
uri = getImageUri(context, bitmap);
```

and here is your getImageUriFunction()

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
            inImage, "", "");
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

After you get your uri, you have to share that on fb with this function

```
share_screen(uri,"facebook");
```

here is that function

```
 public void share_screen(Uri pngUri, final String sharingapp) {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    shareIntent
            .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "your sharing text");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri); // Share
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // image
                                                                        // on
                                                                        // Facebook
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent,
            0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains(sharingapp)) {
            c++;
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                    activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }

    }
    if (c == 1) 
        c = 0;
     else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have " + sharingapp
                        + " installed.");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

    }
}
```

I am just copying it from one of my project, so hope you will understand..!!

Comment: I hope this code snippet is from your recent application code

Comment: This code is working but text is not shared. This is the same problem as in my code.